# How to change NSURLConnection's priority?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection

I'm working on a music app, which use `ASIHTTPRequest` to access to server's api, and use `NSURLConnection` to download music files.

One music file is 10M or so. When downloading music file, access to server's api will be much more slow than not downloading music file.

So I want to change download connection's priority lower. But there is no API to change priority of `NSURLConnection` or `NSURLRequest`.

How to archive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think only NSOperationQueues can be priorized. Here is a link to an example:
http://eng.pulse.me/tag/nsurlconnection/

An alternative would be, to stop downloading the music file an resume it after your other downloads are completed. To do this you could tell ASIHTTP to save a download to a file and resume it on request.

Here is an example from one of my projects:

```
- (void) executeFileDownloadAtURL:(NSURL *) aURL toDirectory:(NSString *) aDestinationPath;
{
    self.request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:aURL];
    [self.request setDownloadDestinationPath:aDestinationPath];
    self.request.downloadProgressDelegate = self.delegate;
    [self.request setAllowResumeForFileDownloads:YES];
    NSString *tmpDir = NSTemporaryDirectory();
    NSString *tempFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", tmpDir, @"TempMovie.mp4"];
    [self.request setTemporaryFileDownloadPath:tempFilePath];
    self.request.showAccurateProgress = YES;
    self.request.delegate = self;
    [self.request startAsynchronous];
}
```