# Message sent to deallocated instance ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, automatic-ref-counting

I am doing an application which downloads image from server and displays it on a view. I am using delegate for that. Once the image is finished loading a delegate sends message to the view to show the image.

The above scenario is working fine. But if I move out from that particular view to any other view, when the image loading is finished the delegate tries to send message and causes an error.

I tried setting the

```
imageFetcher.delegate=nil;
```

in view didUnload. Also before calling the delegate method in download class I check for delegate is nil.

But i can see that the delegate object is not nil.

```
if(delegate!=nil)
{
  [delegate imagefetcherView:self didLoadImage:image];
}
```

How can I fix this error?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure viewDidUnload calling is your code??? I think it could not called it depreciated method in latest ios verion see this doc https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not rely `viewDidUnload` to do any cleanup. That's only called in iOS versions prior to iOS 6, and only when the view is unloaded due to memory pressure (but not when you just dismiss/pop the view).

Set your delegate to `nil` in the `dealloc` method or `viewDidDisappear` or wherever is appropriate.

Two caveats relevant to picking which method you'll `nil` the `delegate`:

1. Be aware that `viewWillDisappear` and `viewDidDisappear` will also be called if you push/present another view controller, even if the current one has not been yet been dismissed. Only rely upon these disappear-related methods if the view controller in question does not ever push/present another view controller.
2. If employing the `dealloc` technique, note that this only works if the `delegate` is a `weak` property of the image fetcher class (and delegates generally should be `weak`). If the `delegate` was a `strong` or `retain` property, that will prevent the view controller's `dealloc` from ever getting called.

By the way, I gather that you are letting the image fetch continue, even though the view controller has been dismissed. You might want to not only `nil` the delegate, but cancel the request, too. It depends upon whether (a) you're using a fetch that even permits a cancellation (e.g. a `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` approach or a AFNetworking operation) and, if so, (b) whether you want it to cancel or not. It's easy, though, to tie up precious network resources (esp if on a slow cellular connection) letting requests continue even if the user doesn't need it anymore. It depends upon the particulars of your app.

Regardless, do not rely upon `viewDidUnload`.

Comment: dealloc is still called in ARC , you just cant release or call `[super dealloc]` in it

Comment: @giorashc No offense, but that's not the case. The `dealloc` is still available and used in ARC. The only difference is that, as Dante says, you don't call `[super dealloc]`. You often don't need a `dealloc` in ARC (since members are generally deallocated for you), but you can still have a `dealloc` method.

Comment: None taken and my mind is blown :) After looking into it you indeed can implement dealloc. When I learned ARC I understood incorrectly that dealloc is forbidden. Thanks for clearing that out.

Comment: I'd advise against clearing the delegate and canceling the request on pop. The user might want to return to the same controller again, why not show the picture?

Comment: @ilyan. You definitely want to clear the `delegate` on pop/dismiss (because if you push/present it again, it will be a new instance). Re canceling, I agree that you may or may not want to cancel (do use-case assessment to see what makes sense for the app). But far too many apps blithely let UI-related network requests continue when the user has long-since moved on and then result in poor performance when the user requests something else because the previous requests are still in progress. IMHO, you should generally prioritize current UI-related requests over previous background ones.

Comment: @Rob, you're right, I still think it's better to have a global long-lived cache (try to not lose incoming data...) but cancel old requests once new requests are made (can we change priority on an existing network request?)

Comment: @Rob Re: *re-prioritizing*. One idea would be to suspend and resume download as necessary: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918800/how-to-change-nsurlconnections-priority

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39025/discussion-between-rob-and-ilya-n)

Answer (score 3):

`viewDidUnload` isnt called in iOS 6+.

you should use this

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
     imageFetcher.delegate=nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You still can have a dealloc call in your class but it should not call [super dealloc]. If you add it you can set up a breakpoint here and see from where its gets its retain count to 0. Or use Instruments to track retain/release cycle of your controller.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a separate cache to temporarily store the picture in care view controller is deallocated but the picture can be used once again, e.g. if the user gets back to the same page.

In that case you would have a long-lived cache object as a `delegate`. View controllers can, for example, subscribe to receive key-value notifications about incoming pictures when those view controllers become visible (just don't forget to unsubscribe from KVO in `viewWillDisappear`).

If your controller is invisible but likely to be shown again you'll have the picture in cache (to be dropped if low memory); of course you can also check in the cache if your picture is never likely to be shown again and drop the picture.